# How to enforce MediaWiki table cell width and wrap?

Tags: mediawiki

I have a table like this and my problem is that Col 0-5 collapse to give space to Col 6 which has very long texts in some cells:

```
{| cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="1" class="prettytable sortable FCK__ShowTableBorders"
|-
! width="200" | <center>Col 0</center>
! width="300" | <center>Col 1</center>
! width="100" | <center>Col 2</center>
! width="60" | <center>Col 3</center>
! width="60" | <center>Col 4</center>
! width="60" | <center>Col 5</center>
! width="120" | <center>Col 6</center>
|-
```

What I want is to make Col 6 collapse instead and word-wrap it's contents, and enforce width of Col 0-5.

I have MediaWiki 1.17.4 which I have no control over to upgrade.

I have found https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Tables#Column_width however I do not understand why does my table not work and thus this page did not help me in that nor in seeing what I should do to make the desired wrapping in Col 6 and prevent collapsing of Col 0-5.

How do I make Col 6 wrap and collapse while make Col 0-5 retain their set sizes?

Comment: What are you using `FCK__ShowTableBorders` for? It doesn't sound needed for what you want and might be interfering. In particular I don't understand what you mean by "collapsing".